# Multiple joins on same table and column using multiple aliases

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a celebrity photo website. It has 1 table that holds all searchable data for each photo called `photoSearch` and the full set of data is spread over many tables (normalization), named `photos`, `photoPeople` and `people`.

Table `photoPeople` contains photoID's and peopleID's and the `people` table contains peopleID's and the people's names. The `photos` table contains captions, headlines, heights, widths, file sizes, sales codes etc etc.

This is my current script which produces good results.

```
SELECT 
     p.photoID, 
     p.setID, 
     p.headline, 
     p.caption,
     GROUP_CONCAT(pe.people ORDER BY pe.people ASC SEPARATOR ';') AS people
FROM 
     photos p
INNER JOIN
     (
        SELECT photoID 
        FROM photoSearch 
        WHERE MATCH (allKeywords, shortCaption)
        AGAINST ('+red +dress +claridges +hotel' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
        LIMIT 50
     ) pids ON p.photoID = pids.photoID
***********
LEFT JOIN
     photoPeople pp ON p.photoID = pp.photoID
LEFT JOIN
     people pe ON pp.peopleID = pe.peopleID
***********
GROUP BY p.photoID
```

The problem is, instead of just selecting celebrity names to display in the results, I now want to search for one or more celebrity names to alter the results.

I'm pretty sure it's not possible to add two or more where clauses on the same column (where pe.people = 'angelina jolie' and pe.people = 'brad pitt'), so I'm pretty sure it needs to be done using JOINS.

This confused me a bit. So I asked a question here on SO to find out how I could achieve this and somebody advised this:

> "Join to the 'photoPeople' and 'people' tables ***n*** times, where ***n*** is the
>   number of people you are searching for."

I tried many different ways of achieving this but so far have failed. I know what he said involves removing the joins in between the two lines of asterisks (code above) and replacing them with ***n*** amount of joins to the people table, but I just can't figure it out.

I tried this but phpMyAdmin has now been thinking for the last 10 minutes!:

```
********
JOIN ( photoPeople AS pp1 JOIN people AS p1 ON pp1.peopleID = p1.peopleID) 
ON p1.people = 'Brad Pitt'
JOIN ( photoPeople AS pp2 JOIN people AS p2 ON pp2.peopleID = p2.peopleID) 
ON p2.people = 'Angelina Jolie'
********
```

On top of the above attempt taking FOREVER, I also struggle to see how I can alter the GROUP_CONCAT function to get the results from more than one join/alias (p1, p2, p3 etc)!

Please, I would love some advice to get this working correctly.

---

**TEST SCENARIO**

If I run my query as-is, this is what I would see:

```
Photo:    120030
Set:      8803
Headline: Brad and Angelina arrive at film premiere.
People:   Brad Pitt; Angelina Jolie

Photo:    120031
Set:      8803
Headline: Brad and Angelina arrive at film premiere.
People:   Angelina Jolie

Photo:    120032
Set:      8803
Headline: Brad and Angelina arrive at film premiere.
People:   Brad Pitt
```

I want my new query to search for names, so if I search for Angeline Jolie and Brad Pitt, I will see only this:

```
Photo:    120030
Set:      8803
Headline: Brad and Angelina arrive at film premiere.
People:   Brad Pitt; Angelina Jolie
```

---

**NEW ATTEMPT:**

No errors but returned 0 results, where there should be 1000's of results for 'Brad Pitt' and 'Angelina Jolie' in 'France'.

```
SELECT 
     p.photoID, 
     p.setID, 
     p.headline, 
     p.caption,
     GROUP_CONCAT(pe.people ORDER BY pe.people ASC SEPARATOR ';') AS people
FROM 
     photos p
INNER JOIN
     (
        SELECT photoID 
        FROM photoSearch 
        WHERE MATCH (allKeywords, shortCaption)
        AGAINST ('+France' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
        LIMIT 50
     ) pids ON p.photoID = pids.photoID
LEFT JOIN
     photoPeople pp ON p.photoID = pp.photoID
JOIN
     people pe ON pp.peopleID = pe.peopleID
     AND (pe.people = 'Angelina Jolie' OR pe.people = 'Brad Pitt')
GROUP BY p.photoID
```

If I remove the INNER JOIN section and run this, it returns all photos of Brad and Angelina whether they are together or not, which is incorrect - I just need them together. If I also remove the `OR pe.people = 'Brad Pitt'`, it returns photos of Angelina correctly, I just can't get the whole thing linked up!

Answer (score 2):

To find photographs showing all the people from a list, use

```
SELECT 
     p.photoID, 
     p.setID, 
     p.headline, 
     p.caption,
     GROUP_CONCAT(pe.people ORDER BY pe.people ASC SEPARATOR ';') AS people
FROM 
     photos p
INNER JOIN
     (
        SELECT photoID 
        FROM photoSearch 
        WHERE MATCH (allKeywords, shortCaption)
        AGAINST ('+red +dress +claridges +hotel' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
        LIMIT 50
     ) pids 
   ON p.photoID = pids.photoID

INNER JOIN
     photoPeople pp ON p.photoID = pp.photoID
INNER JOIN
     people pe ON pp.peopleID = pe.peopleID
-- List of people
WHERE pe.People in ('Angelina Jolie', 'Brad Pit')
GROUP BY p.photoID
-- "2" must match number o people in the list
-- If you add third name, change this to 3
HAVING count(distinct pe.People) = 2
```

I've changed left joins to inner because `where` would treat them as such (as null does not compare to anything) and because I felt that question does not make sense if unmatched photos are accepted.

P.S. Your attempt did not work because it did join all Angelinas to all photos and all Brads to all photos producing vast number of records. You migh have joined two derived tables on PhotoID to produce the same result as the query above, but it would require another derived table to add third name.

```
SELECT photos1.PhotoID
FROM
(
  SELECT pp1.PhotoID
    FROM photoPeople AS pp1 
    JOIN people AS p1 ON pp1.peopleID = p1.peopleID
   WHERE p1.people = 'Brad Pitt'
) photos1
JOIN 
(
  SELECT pp2.PhotoID
    FROM photoPeople AS pp2
    JOIN people AS p2 ON pp2.peopleID = p2.peopleID
   WHERE p2.people = 'Angelina Jolie'
) photos2
  ON photos1.PhotoID = photos2.PhotoID
```

**UPDATE**: combining conditions to avoid possible `limit 50` mismatchs:

```
SELECT 
     p.photoID, 
     p.setID, 
     p.headline, 
     p.caption,
     GROUP_CONCAT(pe.people ORDER BY pe.people ASC SEPARATOR ';') AS people
FROM 
     photos p
INNER JOIN
     (
        SELECT distinct ps.photoID 
        FROM photoSearch ps
        INNER JOIN
             photoPeople pp ON ps.photoID = pp.photoID
        INNER JOIN
             people pe ON pp.peopleID = pe.peopleID
     -- List of people
        WHERE pe.People in ('Angelina Jolie', 'Brad Pit')
          AND MATCH (allKeywords, shortCaption)
              AGAINST ('+red +dress +claridges +hotel' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
        GROUP BY ps.photoID
     -- "2" must match number o people in the list
     -- If you add third name, change this to 3
        HAVING count(distinct pe.People) = 2
        LIMIT 50
     ) pids 
   ON p.photoID = pids.photoID
INNER JOIN
     photoPeople pp ON p.photoID = pp.photoID
INNER JOIN
     people pe ON pp.peopleID = pe.peopleID
GROUP BY p.photoID
```

**RE-EDITED:** noticed that I forgot to leave people-related join in main query.

Comment: Thanks for your input Nikola. I tried your top example but it didn't return any results. I then removed my INNER JOIN SUB SELECT and it worked perfectly. How can I get this working with the INNER JOIN SUB SELECT, because there are definitely photos in 'photoSearch' and 'people' that match the example query.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid Derived table might return different photos than those selected in outer query because of `limit 50`. To test this hypothesis remove `limit 50` and see if there are rows returned. If it is true, you will need to move condition to photoSearch - see the update.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid I've edited the answer again. I noticed that I forgot to leave people-related join in main query.

Answer (score 1):

Are there photos that don't have photoPeople?  Or photoPeople that don't have people?  If not, use a regular join rather than a left join.  You can then put extra where clauses on that query

```
where (people = "Brad Pitt" or people = "Angelina Jolie")
```

If you need to keep the left join, you can add more conditions to the ON

```
... ON pp.peopleID = pe.peopleID and (people = "Brad Pitt" or people = "Angelina Jolie")
```

Update:

My brain was seeing the self-join version rather than Nikola's union:

```
select pp1.photoId
from photoPeople pp1, people p1, photoPeople pp2, people p2
where pp1.peopleID = p1.peopleID
and p1.people = "angelina"
and pp2.peopleID = p2.peopleID
and pp1.photoId = pp2.photoId
and p2.people = "brad"
```

But it reminded me of systems I've build where you want a rank based on the number of matches, which is easier with the UNIONS.

```
 SELECT photoID, count(*) as rank
 from (
  SELECT pp.PhotoID
    FROM photoPeople AS pp 
    JOIN people AS p ON pp.peopleID = p.peopleID
    WHERE p.people = 'Brad Pitt'
  UNION
  SELECT pp.PhotoID
    FROM photoPeople AS pp 
    JOIN people AS p ON pp.peopleID = p.peopleID
    WHERE p.people = 'Angelina Jolie'
 ) foo
 group by photoID
 order by rank desc
```

I'll go upvote Nikola :)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help. There are photos that do not have photoPeople, yes, but all photoPeople have people.

Comment: I've just tried this and it returned 0 results, where it should return hundreds.

Comment: I have just updated my question with 'NEW ATTEMPT' section. Thanks Alain.

Comment: Nothing leaps out immediately, though it's been a long day :)   For testing, I'd simplify by taking out the 'peopleSearch' subquery and confirming that there are rows in 'people' that exactly match "Brad Pitt".

Comment: Okay, I changed the 2nd LEFT JOIN to a JOIN instead, and it returned results. The problem is the OR part is doing the wrong thing. It's returning photos of Angelina on her own and photos of Brad on his own and also some photos where they're together. I only want to show photos where they are together in the same photo, so I tried changing the OR to AND but it returned nothing. The feeling is that I need multiple JOINS...

Comment: Sorry about that - I swear I read an "OR" in your requirements along the way...  I'll add to my answer, above, so I can format the SQL...

Comment: Hey that's okay. Look forward to the addition.